# Are code reloading and laziness two incompatible features in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

One of Haskell's best known feature is its laziness, which permits to write more elegant and reusable code. Internally, laziness builds computations in memory for execution only when needed, which can happen much later at another place in the code. Also, the GHC API can reload new module versions, a feature that some programs use, most notably GHCi.

Now suppose that a lazy computation holds a reference to a function in a module, and the module is reloaded. Which version of the function will be executed when the lazy computation is evaluated to its full extent?

It seems natural that the old version should be executed, because its semantics was the one intended by the time the lazy computation was created, and so running the new version instead seems unreasonable. However, if the old version fails, subsequent debugging will be problematic because the code that failed no longer exists in the system, making it hard to track the cause of the failure.

All this reasoning leads me to think that laziness and code reloading (i.e. hot upgrades) are incompatible at a conceptual level. Is this really so, or is there some design decision in Haskell or GHC that solves this conceptual incompatibility?

Thanks

Comment: When reloading `:r` in GHCi, it looks that all `let x` statements are removed (the variable no longer exists).

Comment: That solves the problem, but is a decision that works only well for an interpreter, such as GHCi. It will not work in general, because most other programs have no way to track what are the pending computations waiting for evaluation that should be disposed upon module reloading. On the contrary, GHCi knows where pending computations are: they are all referenced by the variables the user created in the console, so its easy to dispose them all.

Comment: I guess most systems that support hot-upgrading introduce a layer of indirection at basically every function call or so, namely: look up the most recently loaded version of this function. I see no reason a Haskell implementation couldn't adopt this solution, too, though presumably at each thunk evaluation rather than at each function call.

Comment: As a side note, there appears to be a potentially unwarranted assumption in the argument as posed, namely, that other systems that support hot upgrades are easy to debug because old code is never in the system. But this seems incredibly unlikely; e.g. what happens if the upgrade happens while a function is still executing? Presumably it continues executing, still using the old code path (even if subsequent calls made by this old path are to new functions) for the remainder of that function call.

Comment: @DanielWagner Doing as you say would result in the pending computation to use the semantics of the new version not the semantics of the old version the programmer expects at the time the computation was constructed ... That is why I think laziness is incompatible with hot code swapping / code reloading, that is, you have to have to throw away all pending computations, which in a lazy language seems not only unpractical, but also result in unpredictable behavior when calling the evaluation of those pending computations.

Comment: @DanielWagner In contrast, in imperative languages this is conceptually trivial because there are no such pending computations, so new computations will simply use the new function definition.

Comment: @mljrg I don't believe your claim that "in imperative languages there are no pending computations". If I write `f(int i) { i = i+1; return g(i); }` and do an upgrade after entering `f` but before entering `g`, there is a pending computation of `f`. It seems inevitable to me that you must now choose whether to use the old or new `g`, and it's not at all clear to me that this decision should be significantly different in a strict or lazy language: in both cases, the pros and cons are as you say (new `g` may change the meaning of `f`, old `g` ignores the upgrade and may keep an old bug).

Comment: @DanielWagner That is a good example, and the reasonable behavior should be to have the semantics of both `f` and `g` and whatever other functions `g` calls underneath, as that semantics was the expected by the time the computation was put on hold. However, the new versions of `f` and `g` may have been in effect for quite a while by the time the old computation needs to be evaluated, so even the old semantics is not expected anymore. That is why I think laziness and code reloading do not play well conceptually, because of this time lapse imposed by laziness.

Comment: @DanielWagner In imperative languages the old computation may take a while to reach an internal function that was upgraded (say `g`), which is a situation similar to the laziness case that also results in the same conceptual issue. However, in imperative languages, programmers can easily control such situations, but not in Haskell. (Note: I am not banging on Haskell, I love it, however this issue came along to my mind today. In fact, there must be a reason why hot code upgrading is not a feature in Haskell as much it is in Erlang, and both languages have evolved on par along the years.)

Comment: I've voted to close this as "opinion based" since any answer is clearly going to depend on a lot of specifics and viewpoints.  A more rigidly formalized variant of the question might be more objectively answerable (and the Haskell S.O. crowd would be good people to ask), but it still would fit better with the topics and discussion style of cs.stackexchange or quora than stackoverflow.